# Save every column from a spreadsheet as a separate file

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to add a range from each column from a spreadsheet into a new file and save it named as the content of the top cell in a particular column. The code below copy the content in the template file (the active file in this case), and it should save every cycle from the for loop into a new file. Code itself works as I get the final column in the template after running. But, makeCopy() function copies the initial state of the template file and I get "y" time the same file. Obviously, the process runs in the memory and it isn't synchronized with the file in the drive until the execution is finished. I can't use SpreadsheetApp.open... method to open each file after it is created, because it requires authorization for every file. The real source spreadsheets have up to 300 columns and it isn't acceptable to click for authorization every time. I didn't find any other "save" method in the documentation. Does anyone have idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

```js
/** @NotOnlyCurrentDoc */

function myFunction5() {

/** x - Number of columns */  
let x = 8

/** y - Number of rows */
let y = 8

/** Destination Folder ID, where the generated files will be saved. */
var destFolder  = DriveApp.getFolderById("Destination_Folder_ID");

/** Source spreadsheet file ID */
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source_Spreadsheet_ID");   



var source = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

/** dss is the current template spreadsheet */
var dss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var target = dss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

  
/** i - increment; from 2 to the last column position */
for(var i = 2; i <= x; i ++) {
    
  
  var data = source.getRange(1,i,y,1).getValues();

 /** Copy data to the target range */

  target.getRange(1,2,y,1).setValues(data);


/** Make File copy */
  
  DestinationFilename = source.getRange(1,i,1,1).getValue();
  DriveApp.getFileById(dss.getId()).makeCopy(DestinationFilename, destFolder);

  };

}
```

Comment: Try to add `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before you make a copy of current file.

Comment: Yes, that's it what I need. It works!

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want you should make use of the `flush()` method.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush):

> `flush()` - Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.
>
> Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance, such as when doing multiple calls to Range.getValue(). However, sometimes you may want to make sure that all pending changes are made right away, for instance to show users data as a script is executing.

Therefore, you should add:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

After:

```
target.getRange(1,2,y,1).setValues(data);
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Class - flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush).